# GWT RequerstFactory - Extract code from entity to service locator

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

Let's say I have an entity "MyUser" and I don't want to store all my logic in there. As I understand the docu, I can add the logic to a service locator. I linked the service locator in my request context:

```
@Service(value = MyUser.class, locator = MyServiceLocator.class)
public interface MyUser extends RequestContext {

    InstanceRequest<MyUserProxy, Void> setName(String name);

    Request<Void> changePasswordAndSendMail(String password);

}
```

And defined the locator like this:

```
public class MyServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {
    @Override
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void changePasswordAndSendMail(String password){

        // Do something
    }


}
```

But the compiler complains with:

```
Could not find domain method similar to myPackage.MyUser changePasswordAndSendMail(java.util.String)
```

Is there a way to extract the logic out of the entities?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your logic to be outside `MyUser`, then just change the value of the `@Service` to the class that has that logic (I suppose `@ProxyFor` in the question is a mistake on your part).

If the methods on that class are not `static` then you need a `ServiceLocator` to return an instance of that class. The service locator itself does do anything else than *locate* the service that contains the service methods.

Migrating from a state where methods are `static` in `MyUser`, just create another class, move the `static` methods there (except for the `findMyUser` method of course) and change your `@Service` to point to the new class.

Note that `InstanceRequest` methods still call instance methods on the class pointed to by the `@ProxyFor` annotation on the proxy referenced as the first type argument of the `InstanceRequest`. In your example, `setName` needs to be an instance method on `MyUser` (assuming `MyUserProxy` is annotated with `@ProxyFor(MyUser.class)`)

Comment: Ok, I created a new class, moved my `changePasswordAndSendMail()` method there and linked my RequestContext with `@Service(value = NewClass.class` to it. The validation then finds this method, but the IDE then warns me that there is no `setName()` in `MyUser`.